# How to prevent or override automatic formatting within RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

How would i prevent text from being automatically formatted when added to a RichTextBox, or better yet, override the formatting that does occur?

For instance, the following code sets the text, but then creates a formatted link to a server.

```
rtbSomeField.Text = "\\\\just some text";
```

Results in

[image]

I understand why it's doing this, but is there a way to disable or override that particular feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `DetectUrls` to `false` for the `RichTextBox`

Good luck!

Comment: Oh wow. +1 and accept. I scrolled through Intellisense for the control and completely missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following method to paste text into RichTextBox as plain text.
First, you need to add pasting handler to RichTextBox:

```
System.Windows.DataObject.AddPastingHandler(rtbox, ClearClipboardFormat.OnPaste);
```

Second - change desired format in handler:

```cs
static class ClearClipboardFormat
{        
    public static void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.FormatToApply = DataFormats.Text;            
    }
}
```